# How to run queue tasks on shared hosting in php

Tags: php, queue

I need a script that can help me process a script every 5 seconds on a shared hosting.
I written a script that checks if there is any sms queued in a db, and if any it sends the sms. Cron jobs on my server runs after every 5 mins which is not convenient. I can't install [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) since my server is on shared hosting here my code

```
$query_sch = "SELECT * FROM crbsms_queue LEFT JOIN crbusers ON crbsms_queue.user_id = crbusers.user_id"; 
$sch_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sch);

foreach ($sch_result as $value)
{
     $phone = $value['phones'];
     $sender = $value['sender']; 
     $message = $value['message']; 
     $user_id = $value['user_id'];
     $id = $value['id'];
     $token = $value["access_token"];

     $link_id = NULL;
     $correlator = "$id";
     $endpoint = 'https://example.com/delivery-url.php';

    $version = "v1"; //DONT change unless you are using a different version
    $instance = new BongaTech($token, $version);
    $sms = new Sms($sender, $phone, $message, $correlator, null, $endpoint);
    $instance->sendBatchSMS($sms);
}
```

Comment: You do not have access to change the CRON jobs?

Comment: Before sleeping, execute your code.
for ($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) { sleep(5); }

Comment: my cron jobs settings is atleast 5 min nothing below is accepted

Comment: @bbbbburton how can implement this, are you to write a complete answer for me

Comment: If the hosting provider created the 5-minute limitation, there is nothing you can do about it. Probably it's to protect the server from abuse or bad coding, and ensure it doesn't become inaccessible, either for your site or the other sites hosted on the same server. Either accept the limitation (and maybe inform your users there maybe a short delay before they receive messages, if that's relevant), or find another hosting provider which doesn't restrict you, or get a hosted private server (VPS) where you can do what you want.

Comment: NOTED. was just seeking clarification before I pursue a dedicated or VPS